# What to use for quick gas line disconnect, barb on both sides?

Tags: kegging, tubing

My current setup is:

```
CO2 tank -> regulator -> barb -> tube -> ball lock disconnect ->
keg -> ball lock disconnect -> tube -> barb -> faucet
```

As the gas tube passes through a hole on the side of my refrigerator, and it is cumbersome to remove either side of that tube (regulator side or keg side), I'd like a way to have the following setup instead to be able to take the CO2 tank away easily:

```
CO2 tank -> regulator -> barb -> some disconnect -> some disconnect -> tube -> etc.
```

What do you suggest for the disconnects to use here? The barb on the low pressure side of the regulator could also be something else I guess and then I could have:

```
CO2 tank -> regulator -> some disconnect -> tube -> etc.
```

As long as I can disconnect from close to the regulator and not from the keg, that's what I'm looking for. Note that something that stops the flow of gas (like ball locks do) would be ideal because I don't want the keg to push its CO2 out as soon as I disconnect the regulator (I could also disconnect from the keg first, then disconnect from the regulator, but I'd prefer not to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Full disclosure:** I have not implemented this solution yet but this is the approach to which I'm leaning:

I think I've been trying to solve the same problem. Currently I like the idea of using disconnects like those produced by [CPC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008V1XSPY). They are rated to 120psi, are valved (automatically stop the flow of gas/liquid when disconnected) and I believe they are BPA free. Using these has the added benefit of being able to create an array of quick disconnect components to match different needs (pin/ball kegs, purging attachments, etc...).

The only downside I see to using these is that they appear bulky.

Another idea would be to swap the barbs on your regulator for MFL fittings but they would not facilitate *quickly* removing the gas lines and they are not valved.

Lastly, [this link](http://www.homebrewfinds.com/2011/09/making-utility-co2-line-using-luer.html) on homebrewfinds.com lead me to this solution but I didn't like the Luer disconnects b/c they're not valved and because I had concerns regarding the material they're made of.

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives. I ended up using a simple 2-way manifold with valves. Satisfies my use case without quick disconnects, after all, but I like that you found other options so I'm going to accept this.